# Mutliple Google Tag Manager Containers for one Google Analytics Property

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, tracking

currently I am planing to restructure my tracking. As my website has 4 different main areas, which stand alone for themselves, I want to implement a seperate GTM Container for each area. Each container would send data to a specific GA property:
GTM Container 1 - GA Property 1
GTM Container 2 - GA Property 2
GTM Container 3 - GA Property 3
GTM Container 4 - GA Property 4

So far so good. However, I would also like to track the whole traffic on the entire domain. Therefore, I would like to know if it would be possible to aggregate the data from all 4 GTM Containers in an additional GA Property:

GTM Container 1+2+3+4 - GA Property 5 (entire domain traffic)

Is this possible or will there be problems with the attribution of the user due to the different containers?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.   Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you certainly can have a GTM container conducting/duplicating tracking for multiple properties. So the following scenario is possible and sometimes even viable:

```
Container A -> Property A and Z
Container B -> Property B and Z
Container C -> Property C and Z
Container D -> Property D and Z
```

2. Before you do it, consider Views. Maybe GA Views solve your issue. Having different containers for different parts of the site may be taxing. It will increase the complexity of implementation.
3. Even if you still want to use multiple Properties, why multiple GTM containers? It's easier to report to however many Properties you wish at once in one GTM container. A real reason to spawn additional GTM containers for the same site would be in case your main container is really close to the max size and you can't refactor it properly.
4. Finally, in case it's the Universal Analytics you're using, consider using roll-up reporting as G suggests: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6033415#zippy=%2Cin-this-article